# Nvidia Laptop GPU Artifacts on Screen

Tags: drivers, gpu, nvidia

I have a laptop with an Nvidia GT 650M GPU, and I am noticing that while playing the game World of Goo, I am seeing some black triangular artifacts that flash very quickly on the screen. While this happens, it also seems like the game stutters or drops some frames. This is happening with the latest version of the Nvidia driver. I have not noticed this happening outside of this game, or while running Furmark however.

Could this be hardware damage to the GT 650M GPU? Or could this be a driver/game problem? I have attached some photos of the problem below (please ignore the vertical white lines, that is an issue with the laptop's screen):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Try also updating BIOS and Chipset (usually needed for Video in laptops).

Comment: As above, but very likely is hardware failure.

Comment: I tried updating the BIOS/Chipset drivers along with doing a clean installation of the Nvidia driver and the issue still persisted. I then tried to disable the GT 650M GPU (to use the integrated graphics) and still seen the problem. However after updating the integrated GPU drivers I am no longer seeing the artifacts, I do still see some of the stuttering though. Is it still possible that this is hardware failure still with the integrated GPU or could it be a driver-related issue?